# Flutter Dark Mode

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-theme

I have an old app to update to be Dark Themed, but I have a problem of approaching this task the right way. There is no usage of ThemeData in the MaterialApp prop, just a CustomColorPalette class that is used through the entire app. My question here is, is there a way I can just handle the switch to different colors with one **bool** flag inside the CustomColorPalette class, where I also store that flag in the **SecureStorage** for future reference no matter what way I choose, or should I rework the entire app with the **ThemeData** method?

The color class example:

```
class CustomColorPalette {

///I was thinking something like this
static bool isDarkMode = false;

static Color primaryColor = isDarkMode ? CustomColorDark.primaryColor : CustomColorLight.primaryColor 

static Color secondaryColor = isDarkMode ? CustomColorDark.secondaryColor : CustomColorLight.secondaryColor
…

}
class CustomColorDark {


static Color primaryColor = Colors.black
static Color secondaryColor = Colors.black
…

}
class CustomColorLight {

static Color primaryColor = Colors.white
static Color secondaryColor = Colors.white
…

}
```

on button switch:

```
Switch(
      value: colorThemeValue,
      onChanged: (bool value) => _bloc..add(ToggleThemeEvent(value!))
    );
```

As you can see, **Bloc** is used for state management, this is just an example of how I tried of doing but the **isDarkMode** flag inside the CustomColorPalette class never seems to update on event, only when I refresh the entire app since I store that bool in the SecureStorage. Thanks in advance for your time and effort, much appreciated.